# Python: Zeep Error

Tags: python, soap, zeep, five9

I am using zeep to connect to the Five9 Call Center API in order to retrieve the Call Log Report.

My code is as follows:

```
class Five9api:

    start = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    end = datetime.now()
    user = 'user'
    pwd = 'pwd'
    criteria = {'time': {'end': end, 'start': start}}
    key = None

    def __init__(self, folderName, reportName):
        self.client = None
        self.folderName = folderName
        self.reportName = reportName

    def open_client(self):
        if self.client is None:
            self.client = Five9(self.user, self.pwd)

    def run_report(self):
        identifier = self.client.configuration.runReport(folderName=self.folderName, reportName=self.reportName,
                                                        criteria=self.criteria)
        Five9api.key = identifier

    def get_report_results(self):
        get_results = self.client.configuration.getReportResult(Five9api.key)

        return get_results
```

I am getting an Error when I use the method `run_report` to return a key that is passed onto the method `get_report_results`. What is causing this following error?

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: Result is not ready due to process is not complete
```

The only way around this error is to introduce a `time.sleep` between the aforementioned 2 methods like so...

```
Report = Five9api("Call Log Reports", "Call Log")
Report.open_client()
Report.run_report()
time.sleep(5)
data = Report.get_report_results()
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you retrieve report results with **getReportResult**, you can check if it's ready with **isReportRunning** method:

```
def get_report_results(self):
    while client.service.isReportRunning(identifier=Five9api.key, timeout=100):
        None
    get_results = self.client.configuration.getReportResult(Five9api.key)
```

See full documentation here:
[Configuration Web Services, API Reference Guide](https://webapps.five9.com/assets/files/for_customers/documentation/apis/config-webservices-api-reference-guide.pdf)